# How to minimize voltage loss

Tags: electrical, battery-drain, voltage, voltage-regulator

I have a '79 bike that is currently experiencing voltage loss, causing the battery to die after a couple hours of riding.

It is clear there is lots of corrosion and rust on many of the wires and electrical connectors.

I have two questions.

1. **Voltage loss "adds up" over the entire system, correct? So having 10 rusty connectors causes 10 times a much voltage loss as having 1 rusty connector?**
2. **Which of the following fixes will lower voltage loss?**

A. Switching lights (turn signals, brakes, and headlight) from incandescent to LEDs

B. Cleaning rusty ground-locations on the bike

C. Removing male-female connectors, and instead using a direct wire (no connector)

D. Replacing 16awg wires with 14awg wires

E. Using a soldering iron to connect wires instead of crimp connectors

Comment: Make sure **all** connections are clean and tight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:
1. Yes
2. All

But really, your bikes magneto should be able to keep your battery charged while you're riding without increasing wire size and changing the bulbs. I would clean up the grounds and all connections, put a little dialectic grease on each one, make sure they're tight. If that doesn't solve your issue I'd be more likely to turn my attention to the magneto or battery, lots of auto shops will benchtest that kind of stuff for free.